# Error with using Sass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Hello I am trying to use SASS in a project, but have come across a problem and I was wondering if anyone could help?

I have created two style sheets. One called defaults.scss and one called styles.scss. In the defaults.scss I have declared the following:

`$mainColor: #848484;`

I then try to call the $mainColor in my styles.scss using the following:

```
nav ul { 
 list-style: none outside none;
 margin: 0; font-size: 1.2em;
 color: $mainColor; 
 padding: 50px 0 0 0; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 text-align: center;
}
```

But I get the following error message: `Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$mainColor".`

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have compass running.

Thanks.

Comment: You're importing defaults.scss into styles.scss?

Comment: In the head of my document I have the following: <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/defaults.css"> The defaults.scss is where the $mainColor is declared. The styles.scss is where I am trying to replace the color.

Comment: See sheriffderek's answer. The other advantage to having Compass combine the files is that the browser will make only one request rather than 3.

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly, you have two .scss files. What I normally do is have a styles.scss and in that file you import all of the other .scss style sheets. I think they call them partials or something. So that your main style.scss compiles all of the .scss files together into the .css file. Right now I don't think your two files are aware of each other. your main styles.scss should simply look like this:

```
@import "reset.scss";
@import "global.scss";
@import "structure.scss";
@import "colors.scss";
@import "etc.scss";
```

Make sure they are in your intended cascading order - because that is how they will be smushed together. In your case, default first and then main.

It gets tricky when you start adding media queries too - but this should fix you up I think.

In your html you just need to call your .css file that the whole operation outputs.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` or wherever you have it going to. Just one.

Comment: Yes, `styles.scss` won't know anything about that var (`$mainColor`) unless you import the scss file that contains it.

Comment: Feel free to mark the solution with that sweet little green check mark. I love getting points! I'm such a sucker.

Comment: That's how it works. You upvote all useful help and mark resolved problems, and then you get "points" basically that you can use to pay for difficult answers later.

Comment: Note to self, don't spend your time answering questions for people with reputations under 50.

Comment: @sheriffderek I gave you an upvote ;-) plus, your answer will probably be helpful to someone else in the future.